# FlexSlider 2, 3 слайдера на одной странице, у последнего не показываются стрелочки

Tags: slider

При установке, трех слайдеров на одной странице одновременно, у последнего не показываются стрелочки вперед-назад.

В чем может быть проблема?

Пример подключения:

```
$("#slider-clients").flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: true,
    move: 1,
    controlNav: false,
    customDirectionNav: $(".flex-direction-nav"),
    prevText: "",
    nextText: "",
    itemWidth: 128
}
```

Comment: Приложите весь листинг. По этому обрывку ничего не понятно!
Проверьте у всех ли слайдеров уникальный контейнер для навигации customDirectionNav: $(".flex-direction-nav"),

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, это действительно помогло!)